# Simple client/server program java

Tags: java, sockets, connection

I am trying a a very simple server/client program but can't seem to get it working - "acc" and "waiting for connection" is printed however "connection" is never printed am I doing something wrong ?

Client code:

```
    Socket s;
    String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
    int serverPortNo = 9010;

    public Frame(){

    try{
        s = new Socket(serverIP, serverPortNo);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("error : "+ e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Server code :

```
public class Server {

ServerSocket ss;

public Server(int port){

    try{
        ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        acceptConnections();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void acceptConnections(){
    Socket s;
    System.out.println("acc");

    while(true){
        try{
            System.out.println("waiting for connections");
            s= ss.accept();
            System.out.println("connection");

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("error : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Server(9010);
    new Frame();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start server in a separate thread. For now your main application starts server and waits for clients but client is never started.
Please try to change your `main` method to look like this

```
try {
  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             new Server(9010);
         }
     });
  t.start();
  new Frame();
  t.join();
} catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: It would make more sense to run them as separate programs, as that's the way they'll end up.

Comment: Thanks this works but how would I run them as seperate programs ?

Comment: @JohnCollins to do this you need to write and run 2 different main methods in two different classes (or add main method to both `Server` and `Frame`) and start them from your IDE or command line separately.